# Find Controls placed inside ListView Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, datagrid

```
 <ListView Height="Auto"   Name="lstIndent" SelectionMode="Single" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0"   >
    <ListView.View >
       <GridView x:Name="dgIndentDetails" >
          <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"   >
             <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <!--<GroupBox Header="Department Issue Header" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  >-->
                      <Grid>
                         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"  />
                            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"  />
                         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                         <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsIndentIssue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="chkbxIsChecked" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                         <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding ItemName}" x:Name="lbllstItemName" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></Label>
                         <Label Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Quantity}" x:Name="lbllstQty" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></Label>
                         <Label Grid.Column="3"  Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding IssueQuantity}" x:Name="lbllstIssuedQty" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></Label>
                         <DataGrid  Height="Auto" Padding="10,10,10,10" Width="800" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Name="dgIssuedItemsBatchDetails"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>                                                                 
                               <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemName}">                                                                     
                                  <DataGridTextColumn.Header>                                                                         
                                     <TextBlock Text="ItemName"/>                                                                    
                                  </DataGridTextColumn.Header>                                                                
                               </DataGridTextColumn>                                                                 
                               <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BatchNo}">
                                   <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                                      <TextBlock Text="BatchNo"/>
                                   </DataGridTextColumn.Header>       
                               </DataGridTextColumn>                                                                 
                               <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity}">
                                  <DataGridTextColumn.Header>                                                                         
                                    <TextBlock Text="Quantity"/>                                                                    
                                  </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                               </DataGridTextColumn>
                           </DataGrid.Columns>
                          </DataGrid>
                       </Grid>
                    <!--</GroupBox>-->
                 </DataTemplate>
              </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
       </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

I need to find DataGrid `dgIssuedItemsBatchDetails` and then bind. That `DataGrid` is placed inside `GridView` and that `GridView` is placed inside ListView.

```
GridView grdvwIssueDetail = (GridView)lstIndent.FindName("dgIndentDetails");
```

By using this code I am able to find the `GridView`. My `DataGrid` is placed inside GridView DataTemplate. So suggest me how I can find my `DataGrid` from code behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved by using `VisualTreeHelper`.
As MSDN says:

> VisualTreeHelper class provides utility methods that perform common tasks involving nodes in a visual tree.

So let me show an example how it can be achieved:

```
    private void SeeTheChild()
    {
        DataGrid myCombo = GetVisualChildInDataTemplate<DataGrid>(lstIndent);            
    }
    private T GetVisualChildInDataTemplate<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : Visual
    {
        T child = default(T);
        int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
        {
            Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            child = v as T;
            if (child == null)
            {
                child = GetVisualChildInDataTemplate<T>(v);
            }
            if (child != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return child;
    }
```

`VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent)` returns 0 cause `ListView` is created, but not yet loaded. Particularly, the `DataTemplate` has not yet been applied to the `ListView`, consequently there is nothing in the Visual Tree.
Then use this method to get your `DataGrid` on `Loaded` event of your `Window`:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SeeTheChild();
}
```

**Update:**

To find a control per item in `ListView`:

Create a `SelectionChanged` event:

```
private void listView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   ItemContainerGenerator generator = this.listView.ItemContainerGenerator;
   ListBoxItem selectedItem = (ListBoxItem)generator.ContainerFromIndex(listView.SelectedIndex);
   Label aLabel = GetChildrenByType(selectedItem, typeof(Label), "label") as Label;
   if (aLabel != null)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("We've found Label with name 'label': " + aLabel.Content);
   }
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("There is no such Label");
   }
}
```

and a method which can find a necessary control for you:

```
public static Visual GetChildrenByType(Visual visualElement, Type typeElement, string nameElement)
{
   if (visualElement == null) return null;
   if (visualElement.GetType() == typeElement)
     {
        FrameworkElement fe = visualElement as FrameworkElement;
        if (fe != null)
        {
          if (fe.Name == nameElement)
          {
             return fe;
          }
        }
     }
     Visual foundElement = null;
     if (visualElement is FrameworkElement)
        (visualElement as FrameworkElement).ApplyTemplate();
     for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visualElement); i++)
     {
        Visual visual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visualElement, i) as Visual;
        foundElement = GetChildrenByType(visual, typeElement, nameElement);
        if (foundElement != null)
           break;
     }
     return foundElement;
    }
```

Comment: this is not possile.Our Datgrid is in between ListView. we cannot get the control by writting its name directly..

Comment: it 's not working @StepUp `int controlNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);` this line returns `0` always.

Comment: StepUp, i've tried your code and doesn't work for me. As I said in a comment,  i think GridViewColumns are abstract objects, and are not in the visual tree.

Comment: sorry same result.Can you plz check my xaml file. Actually i need to show data in Parent Child relationship..ListView will show Header and DataGrid will show Detail of that header underneath Header..

Comment: @Rahul are you sure? I've tried your example and it works. You can see it: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D6BDF30773C16E01!2085&authkey=!AOS0zM_V6la-3mQ&ithint=file%2crar

Comment: your code is working but in my case it is showing DataGrid as Null.

Comment: Can you plz tell me about some more other way by which i can show the data as a parent child relationship.

Comment: Ok, i've tried StepUp code and now i think I know what is happening.@Rahul, are you loading any data in your ListView? If you are not, that is why it isn't working...

Comment: @Rahul are you sure that you call `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent)` in `Loaded` event of `Window`?

Comment: so you are binding it in code behind? Because in the xaml you are showing us, `ItemsSource` it's not being binded. Anyway, you also have to use StepUp code in window_loaded or content rendered i believe...

Comment: I'm upvoting StepUp answer anyway,as it works for me

Comment: I've tried after binding `ItemsSource` with fake data and calling `SeeTheChild()` in `Window_ContentRendered` and it returns the `DataGrid`. For me is working

Comment: Finally its works for me but `DataGrid ` did not bind the list.My code bind the data with ListView Again..

Comment: I think that's another problem, your DataTemplate is not ok. You should give this question as answered and open another regarding the malformed DataTemplate

Comment: No my Data Template was ok. i did some silly mistakes.finally it works..Thank you StepUp and Pikoh for your time...Thanks again..

Comment: StepUp i need to find my DataGrid for each and every row.Suppose i got 10 rows from my Database so my datagrid will have 10 replicate.i need to find each gridview row as per index.How i can achieve that.

Comment: @StepUp plz check my new question--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302327/unable-to-find-row-of-datagrid-wpf